# How can I run a Rails controller action manually ("offline")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I need a way to run controller actions manually "offline" and store the result output.

Looking into controller initialization, it seems nothing interesting happens there.

Looking into `send_action`, it seems by the time this is called, the controller instance already knows much about the action! (e.g. `@_action_name`, `@_env`, etv... are already set!).

I need to understand where that happened so I can do in manually to a controller instance. I have never quite figured out how to navigate code as dynamic as Rails, and cannot seem to find out where this set up occurs. I've used `caller` in a few places to understand how actions get called but haven't found the code I'm looking for.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render - is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @SergeySokolov that's for rendering. It assumes I'm already in a controller action, or have the result of a controller action.

Comment: Apologies for asking what I'm sure is a naive question, but what does it mean to run a controller action manually "offline"?

Comment: @jvillian I'm creating a framework similar to what the delayed_action gem provides. The intention is that my team of developers can write an action that will have a long compute time (which would cause a timeout). Instead, transparent to them, their action will be run and rendered asynchronously and a status page rendered instead. The status page will watch for the async result, and display it when ready.

Comment: If I understand what you're describing (which admittedly, I may not), then we do something like this all the time (I think). An action is called. The action kicks off a background job and returns json data that allows the rendered page to check status (which the status page does using js). When completed, the status page makes a call (again, using js) which returns rendered results. Then the status page displays those results. Something like that?

Comment: @jvillian yes. The difference being, I was hoping to make the process completely transparent to the developer. I.e., they extend `AsyncController` instead of `ActionController::Base` and implement the action/view as usual.

Comment: Looks like you can use dispatch action - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L188, like test frameworks emulate actions executing - https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/test_case.rb#L516

Comment: Would also recommend to look into test frameworks like rspec, there you can have test with type: controller so they need to have a way to set this up

Comment: @SergeySokolov there's a lot of setup and pre-existing context required to use what you've linked to. Recreating that setup / context is precisely the complicated part. I'll give points to a full solution.

Comment: Admittedly, our framework is not **completely** transparent to the developer as they do have to include a js listening widget on the status page. That's about as transparent as we could figure. So, I'll look forward to the right answer to your question as I'm sure we'll learn a lot.

Comment: you can save params/headers etc and run delayed action through test framework - funny not complicated option :) If seriously, the simple way that you want is unlikely to be found, in most cases the render_to_string used, the actions themselves are not executed

Comment: @SergeySokolov When the action is invoked, the controller has access to Rak/Rails env variable. What do I need from that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose by running offline you mean, run it via code in the rails console, or some sort of lib or model.

You can access a controller information using the following command:

**`ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)`**

This will create a new session (similar to integration tests session), where you can perform requests to the rails application.

You perform a request to your action/controller in the following manner:

**`session.get(path)`**

To capture the ouput, you can use the value store in **`session.response`** and if you want to get the body, you can use: **`session.response.body`**

Example:

Let's say you have the following controller:

```
# app/controllers/tests_controller.rb

class TestsController < ApplicationController
  layout false
  def index
    @name = 'Test'
  end
end
```

and the following view:

```
# app/views/tests/index.html.erb

Hi <%= @name %>
```

the following routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
...
resources :tests, only: :index
...
```

you can create the following file:

```
# run.rb
session = ActionDispatch::Integration::Session.new(Rails.application)
path = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.tests_path
session.get(path)
puts session.response.body
```

and run it via: **`rails runner run.rb`**, you should get 'Test'